# An array for multiple LHS assignment cannot contain LEX_TS_STRING error

Tags: matlab

New to programing in matlab. I am currently trying to make a MATLAB program that will find the critical values of a multi-variable function and tell me whether each are a minimum, maximum, or saddle point. Unfortunately I always get the error : An array for multiple LHS assignment cannot contain LEX_TS_STRING

Any help will be very appreciated.

here's the code:

```
function [c,d] = critcalpoints(f)

syms x y
f(x,y)=x^3-3*x^2+5*x*y-7*y^2;
gradf = jacobian(f(x,y));
hessmatf = jacobian(gradf,[x,y]);
[xcr,ycr]=solve(gradf(1),gradf(2));
H1=subs(hessmatf,[x,y],[xcr(1),ycr(1)]);
H2=subs(hessmatf,[x,y],[xcr(2),ycr(2)]);
eig(H1);
eig(H2);
c = double(eig(H1));
d = double(eig(H2));
if (c(1) > 0 && d(1) > 0) || (c(2) > 0 && d(2) > 0)
print([xcr,ycr],' is a minimum')
elseif (c(1) < 0 && d(1) < 0) || (c(2) < 0 && d(2) < 0)
print( [xcr, ycr], ' is a maximum')
elseif (c(1) < 0 && d(1) > 0) || (c(1) > 0 && d(1) < 0)
print( [xcr, ycr], ' is a saddle point')
elseif (c(2) < 0 && d(2) > 0) || (c(2) > 0 && d(2) < 0)
print( [xcr, ycr], ' is a saddle point')
elseif (c(1)==0 || d(1)==0)
print( [xcr, ycr], ' is degenerate')
elseif (c(2)==0 || d(2)==0)
print( [xcr, ycr], ' is degenerate')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce your error.  The code can work but you need to change `print` to something else as `print` doesn't do what you think it does.  The [`print`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) function prints a figure that is open to file.  Change it so that you display `xcr` and `ycr` first then display the right condition to satisfy after. Use `disp` instead:

```
syms x y
f(x,y)=x^3-3*x^2+5*x*y-7*y^2;
gradf = jacobian(f(x,y));
hessmatf = jacobian(gradf,[x,y]);
[xcr,ycr]=solve(gradf(1),gradf(2));
H1=subs(hessmatf,[x,y],[xcr(1),ycr(1)]);
H2=subs(hessmatf,[x,y],[xcr(2),ycr(2)]);
eig(H1);
eig(H2);
c = double(eig(H1));
d = double(eig(H2));
disp([xcr, ycr]); % Display the solutions first

if (c(1) > 0 && d(1) > 0) || (c(2) > 0 && d(2) > 0)
disp('is a minimum')
elseif (c(1) < 0 && d(1) < 0) || (c(2) < 0 && d(2) < 0)
disp('is a maximum')
elseif (c(1) < 0 && d(1) > 0) || (c(1) > 0 && d(1) < 0)
disp('is a saddle point')
elseif (c(2) < 0 && d(2) > 0) || (c(2) > 0 && d(2) < 0)
disp('is a saddle point')
elseif (c(1)==0 || d(1)==0)
disp('is degenerate')
elseif (c(2)==0 || d(2)==0)
disp('is degenerate')
end
```

I get:

```
[     0,       0]
[ 59/42, 295/588]

is a maximum
```